# Databricks SQL Reduce function

Tags: sql, databricks

I have a column of type `MAP<STRING, ARRAY<STRUCT<start: FLOAT, end: FLOAT>>>` and I want to calculate the sum of difference between the tuples, i.e. `SUM(end - start)`.

I wrote the below query but I am getting an error. Any help or guidance(or links) on how to write similar queries is very appreciated. Thanks.

```
SELECT
REDUCE(column_name['A'], 0.0, (acc, value) -> value['end'] - value['start'] + acc) summed_values
from table_name
```

error:

```
Error: Error in SQL statement: UnresolvedException: Invalid call to dataType on unresolved object, tree: lambda 'value[end]
```

example column value:

```
{
"A": [{"start": 95.5, "end": 105.5}, {"start": 9.5, "end": 10.5}, {"start": 99.5, "end": 105.5}], 
"B": [{"start": 95.5, "end": 105.5}, {"start": 9.5, "end": 10.5}]
}
```

Comment: should be aggregate, not reduce

Comment: Thanks but that doesn't work either.
```SELECT column_name['A'], 
AGGREGATE(column_name['A'], struct(0.0), (acc, value) -> struct(CAST(value['end'] - value['start'] + acc['col1'] AS DECIMAL(1, 1)))) summed_values
from table_name``` gives me `{'col1': null}`

Comment: The below query works:
`SELECT column_name['A'],  AGGREGATE(column_name['A'], struct(0.0d), (acc, value) -> struct(value['end'] - value['start'] + acc['col1']))) summed_values from table_name`